# Replace default search box with custom search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables and I have two search box displayed in output, but I want only custom search box to be displayed.

How I can hide default DataTables search box?

Only custom search box is required.

## HTML

```
<div class="tab-inn">
   <div class="table-responsive table-desi">
       <table class="table table-hover">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Part Number</th>
                  <th>Bid</th>
                  <th>Model</th>                                          
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

           <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){ ?>
               <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['partnumber']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['bid']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $row['model']; ?></td>
               </tr>
            <?php   } ?>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" />
```

## JavaScript

```
<script> 
   $(document).ready(function (){
       var table = $('table').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print','pageLength']
       });

       $('#mySearch').on('keyup redraw', function() {
            var searchString = '(' + $('#mySearch').val().split(' ').join('|') + ')';

            table.search(searchString, true).draw(true);
       });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Where is the field with ID mysearch?

Comment: <input type="text" id="mySearch" placeholder="custom search ">

Comment: you can use `$('MySelector').hide();` to hide an element with jQuery. If you want to do it automatically, you can integrate that in a document.ready block, or integrate it with a relevant function where you wish to have the functionality. Your question is a bit poorly worded/structered to give much more information I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude `f` (stands for `f`iltering) from value for [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option.

For example:

```
dom: 'Brtip'
```

See official documentation for [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option for more information.